# Need to pass a querystring variable in MVC, so i can use it with jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, query-string

I would like to create this url `blah.com/preview?h=yes`

so i can do this

```
<% if request.querystring("h") = "yes" then %>
jquery stuff
<% else %>
don't do jquery stuff
<% end if %>
```

Comment: id like to implement the code above on the aspx page

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HTML helper:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "some text", 
    "someaction", 
    "somecontroller", 
    new { h = "yes" },
    null
) %>
```

Assuming default routes this will generate the following link:

```
<a href="/somecontroller/someaction?h=yes">some text</a>
```

Or if you want to generate only the link you could use the Url helper:

```
<%= Url.Action(
    "someaction", 
    "somecontroller", 
    new { h = "yes" }
) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a property on your view model that you can inspect.

E.g. **ViewModel**

```
public class SomeActionViewModel
{
    public bool DoJquery { get; set; }
}
```

**Action** (called via `http://www.myawesomesite.com/somecontroller/someaction?h=yes`)

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string h)
{
    var viewModel = new SomeActionViewModel();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(h) && (h.ToLower() == "yes"))
        viewModel.DoJquery = true;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeActionViewModel>" %>

<% if (ViewModel.DoJquery) { %>
    <!-- Do jQuery -->
<% } else { %>
    <!-- Don't do jQuery -->
<% } %>
```

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to be doing it like that from the server.

You could instead follow an [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)/[Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) approach.